# SQL Help in procedure IN statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I ve follow procedure im SQL Server:

```
      alter procedure sp_selectfFriends_by_cities
        (
            @txt_id_usuarios varchar(300)
        )
        as
        begin
        declare @sql varchar(300)
        set @sql = 'select
                     a.int_id_usuario, 
                     a.int_id_cidade,
                     b.txt_nome_cidade,
                     b.txt_nome_estado 
                     from
                      tb_cidades_visitadas a 
                      left join 
                      tb_cidades 

      b on b.int_id_cidade = a.int_id_cidade
 where int_id_usuario in (' + @txt_id_usuarios + ')'
                execute(@sql) 
        end
```

Where @txt_id_usuarios is a list of users separated by commas,and the field int_id_usuario is type of BIGINT.
ie:

```
'6663225047,1122675730,1591119304,1664930592,1685923789,100000235882380,100000292471037,100000466411115'
```

When i try to execute it passing that string as parameter,it returns me follow error:
Incorrect syntax near '1685923789'.

But there is NO incorrect syntax.

Stranger if I remove some IDs it works.
I.E:

```
'6663225047,1122675730,1591119304,1664930592'
```

Works fine!

Any ideias?

Comment: Not sure about the error but your proc isn't very secure. Try reading up an parameterized sql and sql injection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes

declare @sql varchar(300)

This will limit your string to 300 chars.  You need to make it longer

Comment: OMG you are genius! (oh,maybe not...maybe Im too stupid!) THKs!!

Comment: The example they've given isn't more then 300 chars.

Comment: I wonder why SQL does not warn me that, instead of keep saying:Incorrect syntax near '1685923789'.

Comment: @user257234: because it's only parsed when you run `execute(@sql)`